# Stolz region - stuck with the proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Given two points $z_1,z_2$ such that $ \lvert z_i\rvert<1$, show that for every point $z\ne 1$ in the closed triangle with vertices $z_1,z_2,1$ following holds: $$ \frac{\lvert 1-z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\le K,$$ where $K$ is a constant that depends only on $z_1, z_2.$
Determine the smallest value of $K$ for $z_1= \frac{1+i}{2}, z_2=\frac{1-i}{2}$.

What I tried, it's to write $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $r<1$, I'll prove the result but for  $\left(\dfrac{\lvert 1-z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\right)^2$ $= \dfrac{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}{1-2r+r^2}$, and $\theta$ is bounded by the angles of $z_i$ but I can't see, what I can do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: It's better to write $z = 1 - r e^{i\theta}$.  Then $|1 - z| = r$, while $|z|$ can be obtained using the Law of Cosines.

EDIT.  Well, I might as well summarize the whole thing now.  Use polar coordinates centred on $1$ rather than $0$, so $z = 1 - r e^{i\theta}$.  The two points $z_1$ and $z_2$, and therefore also the triangle, are contained inside some sector $-\pi/2 < -\theta_1 \le \theta \le \theta_1 < \pi/2$, and also inside some smaller circle $r = 2 p \cos \theta$ of radius $p < 1$ with centre on the real axis and passing through $1$, as in the picture below:

[image]

For all $z\ne 1$ in the shaded region, and in particular for points in the triangle,
$$
\frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|} = \frac{r}{1-\sqrt{1 + r^2 - 2 r \cos \theta}} = \frac{1}{2  \cos \theta - r} \left(1 + \sqrt{1+r^2 - 2 r \cos \theta}\right)
$$

Now $2 \cos \theta - r = (2 - 2p) \cos \theta + 2 p \cos \theta - r \ge (2 - 2 p) \cos \theta_1 > 0$, while $1 + \sqrt{1 + r^2 - 2 r \cos \theta} = 1 + |z| \le 2$, so we get
$$ \frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|} \le \frac{1}{(1-p) \cos \theta_1}$$

Comment: I don't know How I can bound $\theta$ , specially in the case $z= 1-re^{i\theta}$  sorry for being so stupid!!

Comment: There will be two values of $\theta$ for the two points $z_1, z_2$, and $\theta$ will be between those for every point of the triangle.

Comment: Yes, but this is true when I take $z=re^{i\theta}$ in your change of variables, I don't know how to bound $\theta$ (the relation between $r_1e^{i\theta_1} \to 1-r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ it's not trivial

Comment: **Don't** take $z = r e^{i\theta}$, take $z = 1 - r e^{i\theta}$.
$z_1$ is some point in the open unit disk.  It is $1 - r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ for some $r_1$ and $\theta_1$ with $-\pi/2 < \theta_1 < \pi/2$.  Note that $r_1 < 2 \cos(\theta_1)$ (points $z_1$ with $r_1 = 2 \cos(\theta_1)$ would be on the circle, since $-1$, $1$ and $z_1$ would form a right triangle).

Comment: If $\frac{-\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $0<cos(\theta)<1$. Let's take $z=1-re^{i\theta}$. Then $$
\eqalign{
  & \frac{{\left| {1 - z} \right|}}
{{1 - \left| z \right|}} = \frac{r}
{{1 - \sqrt {1 - 2r\cos \theta  + r^2 } }} = \frac{r}
{{2r\cos \theta  - r^2 }}\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 - 2r\cos \theta  + r^2 } } \right)  \cr 
  &  = \frac{1}
{{2\cos \theta  - r}}\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 - 2r\cos \theta  + r^2 } } \right) \cr} 
$$  I can't use the information (and neither prove it) that $2cos\theta -r > 0 $ I'm very stupid ...

Comment: For $p > 0$, the curve $r = 2 p \cos \theta$, $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, describes a circle of radius $p$ centred at $1-p$ on the real axis.  For some $p \in (0,1)$, this circle contains both $z_1$ and $z_2$, and then it contains the triangle.  If $z = 1 - r e^{i\theta}$ is in this circle, 
$2 \cos \theta - r \ge (2 - 2 p) \cos \theta$.

Comment: I'm the worst mathematician of the world, I'm still stuck with the problem even with all those hints ..... >.<  The only that I can see to do, with that inequality, it's to replace $\frac{1}{2cos\theta-r}$ $\le$ $\frac{1}{(2-2p)cos\theta}$ for some p, that contains both $z_i$ and now <.< . Sorry for being so so stupid!

Comment: @Daniel Another way to look at this: The line segment at angle $\theta$ connecting $(1,0)$ to the circle $|z| = 1$ has length $2\cos(\theta)$. But each of the other two vertices of the triangle isn't all the way over to the circle; it is in the interior of the disk. So there's some $\delta > 0$ such that $2\cos(\theta) - r > \delta$ at this point. Similarly, a compactness argument shows that there's a $\delta > 0$ such that $2\cos(\theta) - r > \delta$ at *all* points in the triangle since the whole triangle is in the interior of the disk.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Robert, I'm not sure if you can do that always. (Put  both points in that circle, the circle $r=2pcos(\theta)$ has center and radius $ = p$ (and not center $1-p$ ) In some cases, that circle, "escapes" from the unit ball

Comment: Remember, the origin of these polar coordinates is $1$, not $0$.  So $p=1$ is the circle $|z|=1$.

Comment: $r = 2p \cos \theta$ is the polar form of a circle centered at $(p,0)$ and radius $p.$ In the above case there is only one such $p$ (as the point $1$ is lying on the  circle) which is $\frac 1 2.$ Rather you need to choose a $p \geq 0$ for which the triangle of interest (formed by the vertices $z_1,z_2$ and $1$) is entirely contained in the circle. So you would need your $p$ to satisfy something like $$\begin{align*} p & = \max \left \{\frac {1 -|z_1|^2} {2 (1 - \mathfrak R (z_1))}, \frac {1 -|z_2|^2} {2 (1 - \mathfrak R (z_2))}, 1 \right \}. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in describing $p$ in my last comment. It would be the following $:$ $$0 \lt p \lt \min \left \{\frac {1 - |z_1|^2} {2(1 - \mathfrak R(z_1))}, \frac {1 - |z_2|^2} {2(1 - \mathfrak R (z_2))} \right \}.$$