# A question about a triangle circumscribed in the unitary complex disk

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ be the unitary complex disk. Given $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{D}$, for every $z\neq 1$ show that in the closed triangle $1,z_1,z_2$, we have $$\dfrac{|1-z|}{1-|z|}<K,$$ where $K$ is a constant only depending on $z_1$ and $z_2$.

My attempt:

I tried to consider the line passing through $1$ and $z$ and the intersection point of such line with the line joining $z_1$ with $z_2$ and try to get relations between $z$ and this line, but I couldn't figure out how to get the constant $K$. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stolz region - stuck with the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190185/stolz-region-stuck-with-the-proof) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%7C1-z%7C%7D%7B1-%7Cz%7C%7D%5Clt%20K%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5C%7Bz%5Cin%5Cmathbb%7BC%7D%3A%7Cz%7C%5Clt%201%5C%7D%24&p=1). FYI, there's also the related [Why $\frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|}\le K$ corresponds to the region defined by the Stolz angle?](/q/647025).

Comment: @JohnOmielan, I didn't know about this Approach Zero tool, thanks for sharing it!